# Find the order of the function(recurrence)

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursion

I am trying to find the order of the following recurrence:
$Q\left(1\right)\:=\:1\:$; $Q\left(n\right)\:=\:Q\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\right), n > 1$.

From what I can tell the value of this function is always $Q\left(1\right)\:=\:1$, because we will always have the following:
$Q\left(n\right)\:=\:Q\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\right) = Q\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{2^2}\rfloor\right) = Q\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{2^3}\rfloor\right) = ... =Q\left(1\right)\:=\:1$. So the order is $\Theta(1)$

Am I correct or maybe I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, you aren't missing anything. The function is actually equal to $Q(x)=1$.

However, if I were you, I'd double check if you didn't miss something from the definition of $Q$.

Comment: Maybe the recurrence was intended to be be Q(n) = Q(floor of n/2) + O(1). In this case it looks like the order would be Theta(lgn) right ?

Comment: @Student Maybe the question was supposed to be "solve $x^2-3=0$", and then, the answer would be still more different. Such speculation is futile.